# api.ai domain intent query response

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es

In API.AI, for creating bots, I've been trying a few intents like news.search, finance.stocks etc. Results of Actions show successful execution as json shows all parameters and successful execution. But where do I find the RESULTS ? 
For example : In Intent "finance.stocks user query "Current stock value of Twitter" is successfully executed capturing the stock name as I see in json log.

But where to get the Actual value of stock or news data etc with these?

Answer (score 0):

Api.ai is a middleman that helps you parse spoken commands. It does not provide you with actual data.

The very [last step of their own introductory tutorial](https://docs.api.ai/docs/get-started#step-5-integrate) explains this. You will need to integrate via one of the provided methods, such as [webhooks](https://docs.api.ai/docs/webhook).

Comment: Thanks a lot Serg.

Comment: @sjsingh you're welcome, accept my answer when you can.